# Running mysqlimport on a MyISAM table for hours, Data_length stays at 0

Tags: mysql, import, myisam

I'm trying to import a fairly large file (5Gb, ~130M records) into a MyISAM table (mysql 5.1.61). It's been running for more than 5 hours now with no errors displayed, and I can see "LOAD DATA INFILE ..." in the process list.

However, when I run SHOW TABLE STATUS, "Data_length" for the table being updated is still 0. I wonder if that's normal - if not, I should probably abort the import to see what's wrong.

"Update_time" displayed by SHOW TABLE STATUS is up-to-date and changes quickly.

Is it normal for "Data_length" to remain zero while mysqlimport is successfully running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the data_length field is computed after the mysqlimport is finished.

Chek the size of the data file .MYD under /mysql/install/path/databasename/table.MYD and see if it is growing.